# EF6 DbSet<T> returns null in Moq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, entity-framework-6

I have a typical Repository Pattern setup in my application with a `DbContext` (EF6):

```
public class MyDbContext : EFContext<MyDbContext> {

    public MyDbContext () { }

    public virtual DbSet<CartItem> Cart { get; set; }
```

and a repository:

```
public class GenericEFRepository<TEntity, TContext>
    where TEntity : class, new()
    where TContext : EFContext<TContext> {

    private readonly TContext _context;

    public GenericEFRepository(TContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }
    //...
    public virtual TEntity Insert(TEntity item) {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);
    }
```

I'm testing this with Moq 4.2 (following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx)) by creating a mock context:

```
        // Arrange
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<CartItem>>();

        var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Cart).Returns(mockSet.Object);

        // Act
        var service = new GenericEFRepository<CartItem, MyDbContext>(mockContext.Object);
        service.Insert(new CartItem() {
            Id = 1,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            UserId = 1,
            Detail = string.Empty
        });

        // Assert
        mockSet.Verify(s => s.Add(It.IsAny<CartItem>()), Times.Once());
```

The problem is that when I reach this line:

```
return _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(item);
```

`_context.Set<TEntity>()` returns null.  After some googling it seems in EF5 it was necessary to return `IDbSet<T>` for Moq to mock the set, but not with EF6.  Is this not the case, or am I missing something?

Comment: Am I missing where you set up the `Set<T>()` method to return the `mockSet`?

Comment: You'll have to clarify that.  According to the tutorial I linked to, the only dealings with the set are the lines `var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<CartItem>>();` and `mockContext.Setup(c => c.Cart).Returns(mockSet.Object);`.

Comment: That's true, but no where in the tutorial's service code (after a quick skim) do I see them calling `Set<T>()`, while yours does.  Add a setup for that and I think it will work.

Comment: Looks like you're right!  I guess I assumed since `Cart` and `.Set<CartItem>()` were referring to the same thing that setting up `Cart` was sufficient.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a setup for the `Set<T>()` method:

```
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<CartItem>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

Even though on the real `EFContext` the property `Cart` and `Set<CartItem>()` refer to the same object, the *mock* of the context doesn't know that, so you need to tell it explicitly what to return.

Since it was a loose mock, the call to a method that hasn't been setup returns the default value, which in this case is `null`.  Strict mocks are nice in helping find this error, but also [have maintenance costs that other folks don't want to deal with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996554/1698557).

Comment: Also might need to mock out other functions on the DbSet.

Comment: @Patrick It does not work for me. EF6 and the code is mostly the same. But I do the test on my service which access to my context via repository. So what is the solution?

Comment: You will be surprised but i didn't setup mockContext with DbSet and all works fine. But in code I need use property name as in example  - property Cart. if I use with Set<Entity> then it coundn't initialize DbSet.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is still correct for me at the end of 2020 with EntitiFramework Core.
Not so easy to understand how to mock objects/datasets, I'm starting right now to implement some Integration tests using in-memory DB with mocked data.
I saw my method worked correctly for example if I do:

```
await _dbcontext.MyEntirySet.ToListAsync();
```

but failed when using equivalend in a generic Repository

```
_dbcontext.Set<TEntity>  : this return a null dataset.
```

I can confirm mocking  Set fix the problem even with EntityFramework Core.

```
 _dbContextMock.Setup(c => c.Set<MyEntityType>()).Returns(mock.Object);
```