# How make a module test by Moq, ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

I have a method, it returns me the return view do ajax operation, how I can test it to check the right data return or not?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ViewPlayers(string teamName)
    {
        if (teamName.Contains("Все игроки"))
        {
            return PartialView(playerRepository.Players.ToList());
        }
        else
        {

            if (teamName != string.Empty)// send team-logo image path
            {
                Team findingTeam = teamRepository.Teams.First(t => t.Name.Contains(teamName));
                ViewBag.TeamLogoPath = findingTeam.Path;
            }
            List<Player> allTeam = playerRepository.Players.Where(t => t.Team.Name.Contains(teamName)).ToList();

            return PartialView(allTeam);
        }
    }
```

[image]

when I choose a team in the drop-down list I take `string name` to post after that,

1) if `"Все игроки"` i take a table with all players

2) else I find the player in this team.

how check-in test return it all player or certain players of the team?

Comment: You pass in the arguments to get the desired condition making sure to mock the dependencies to behave as expected. After invoking the action under test you check the model of the action result and assert that it is the expected data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply calling that method and checking the response? The nice thing about MVC frameworks is that you *don't* need the entire framework just to use a controller. Other components in the stack will take the ActionResult and render it into HTML.

[PartialView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) returns a [PartialViewResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.partialviewresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) whose [Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.viewresultbase.model?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_ViewResultBase_Model) property contains the model passed to `PartialView`.

You should be able to write a unit test that creates a controller, calls the action and checks the result's model, eg :

```
[Test]
public void viewPlayers_Returns_One()
{
    var myController=new MyController(...);
    var resultView=(PartialViewResult)myController.ViewPlayers("SomeName");
    var players= (List<Player>)resultView.Model;

    Assert.That(players, Has.Exactly(1).Items);
}
```

**Mocking**

The tricky part now is injecting the repository. Given the LINQ-like syntax I'd assume `playerRepository` is an EF repository injected through the constructor or a repository object that exposes EF entities through the `Players` property.

Mocking EF is shown in multiple [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569382/ef6-dbsett-returns-null-in-moq) and the [EF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking).

*EF Core* makes mocking a lot easier through its [in-memory database provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810039/moq-and-setting-up-db-context). EF Core isn't tied to the .NET runtime which means it can be used in Full framework applications too. [Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) in the docs contains a more detailed example. There's also an example that shows [using SQLite for more advanced scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)

Being lazy, I'll assume the repository is a class that implements an interface :

```
public interface IPlayersRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Player> Players {get;}
}
```

It's easy to create a mock class that takes a list or array or players and exposes it through `Players` :

```
class MockPlayers
{
    public IQueryable<Player> Players {get; private set;}

    public MockPlayers(Player[] players)
    {
        Players=players.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

That's simple enough that it doesn't even need a mocking framework. After that, the test becomes :

```
[Test]
public void viewPlayers_Returns_One()
{
    var players=new[]{new Player{Name="SomeName"},new Player{Name="Other Name"}};
    var mockRepo=new MockPlayers(players);
    var myController=new MyController(mockRepo);
    ...
}
```

Moq would be useful for a more complex interface. Using Moq, you'd probably write :

```
var players = new[]{...};
var mockRepo=new Mock<IPlayersRepository>();
mockRepo.SetupGet(x => x.Players).Returns(players.AsQueryable());
```

**EF Core**

If you inject an EF Core context, eg PlayersContext, you can configure it to use the in-memory provider :

```
//setup
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PlayersContext>()
    .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Players Test")
    .Options;

using(var ctx = new PlayersContext(options))
{
    ctx.Players.Add(new Player{...});
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}

//Execute
using(var ctx = new PlayersContext(options))
{
    var myController=new MyController(ctx);
    ...
}
```

**"Classic" EF**

Things are a bit more involved and require mocking the DbSet and some of its methods. Adapting the [documentation's query scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#testing-query-scenarios) would look like this:

```
//Setup 
...
var data = players.AsQueryable();

var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Player>>();
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Player>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Player>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Player>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
mockSet.As<IQueryable<Player>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var mockContext = new Mock<PlayerContext>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

//Execute
var myController=new MyController(mockContext.Object);
...
```

Did I mention EF Core can be used in Full Framework applications?

Comment: in this case `Assert.That(players, Has.Exactly(1).Items);` , That (non-invocable member) and Has(name doesn't exist)  error message

Comment: @Andrei update the code to match your unit testing framework. That's [valid NUnit syntax](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/ExactCountConstraint)

Comment: Thank you for helping, I make test for both case