# Mock.Of<Object> VS Mock<Object>()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

I'm currently confuse on how to mock.

I'm using Moq. To mock objects I usually write this way

```
 var mockIRepo = new Mock<IRepo>();
```

However, I need to create mock object for my setup.

**Option1**
Is it better to mock my object which only contain properties this way?

```
 var object = Mock.Of<Object>()
```

**Option2**
Or this way

```
 var object = new Mock<Object>()
```

I've read that option 2 has setupproperties which is kinda questionable to me because I could also set the properties in option 1.

***Then what is the difference? Or is there a better way?***

Comment: Here's the answer - https://cmatskas.com/improve-your-unit-tests-with-mock-of/

Answer (score 76):

This post helped me to understand Mock.Of<T> :
[Old style imperative Mock<T> vs functional Mock.Of<T>](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/)

As explained in the post, with Mock.Of<T> you're saying "Give me a mock that behaves like this" (or Mock**s**.Of<T> if you need to get many objects (IEnumerable)). It makes the declaration of a mock more concise.

Example with Mock<T> (returns a Mock)

```
var el1 = new Mock<IElementInfo>();
el1.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
el1.Setup(x => x.Multiplicity).Returns(Multiplicity.Single);

var c1 = new Mock<ICollectionInfo>();
c1.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
c1.Setup(x => x.Multiplicity).Returns(Multiplicity.Multiple);

var p1 = new Mock<IPropertyInfo>();
p1.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
p1.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Foo" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
p1.Setup(x => x.Type).Returns("System.String");

var p2 = new Mock<IPropertyInfo>();
p2.Setup(x => x.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
p2.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Bar" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
p2.Setup(x => x.Type).Returns("System.String");

var elementInfoMock = new Mock<IElementInfo>();
elementInfoMock.Setup(e => e.Id).Returns(Guid.NewGuid());
elementInfoMock.Setup(e => e.Multiplicity).Returns(Multiplicity.Multiple);
elementInfoMock.Setup(e => e.Elements)
    .Returns(new List<IAbstractElementInfo>
    {
        el1.Object,
        c1.Object,
    });
elementInfoMock.Setup(x => x.Properties).Returns(
    new List<IPropertyInfo>
    {
        p1.Object,
        p2.Object,
    });

this.elementInfo = elementInfoMock.Object;
```

Same example using Mock.Of<T> (returns an instance of the class)

```
this.elementInfo = Mock.Of<IElementInfo>(x =>
x.Id == Guid.NewGuid() &&
x.Multiplicity == Multiplicity.Multiple &&
x.Elements == new List<IAbstractElementInfo>
{
    Mock.Of<IElementInfo>(e => e.Id == Guid.NewGuid() && e.Multiplicity == Multiplicity.Single),
    Mock.Of<ICollectionInfo>(e => e.Id == Guid.NewGuid() && e.Multiplicity == Multiplicity.Single),
} &&
x.Properties == new List<IPropertyInfo>
{
    Mock.Of<IPropertyInfo>(p => p.Id == Guid.NewGuid() && p.Name == "Foo" + Guid.NewGuid() && p.Type == "System.String"),
    Mock.Of<IPropertyInfo>(p => p.Id == Guid.NewGuid() && p.Name == "Foo" + Guid.NewGuid() && p.Type == "System.String"),
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Based on the answers above, I guess when you mostly want to mock properties, `Mock.Of<T>()` is easier, whereas when you want to mock methods etc., `Mock<T>` is easier.

- Mostly mocking properties:

```cs
var foo = Mock.Of<Foo>();
foo.Property1 = 1;
foo.Property2 = 2;
foo.Property3 = 3;
```

- Mostly mocking methods:

```cs
var barMock = new Mock<Bar>();
barMock.Setup(bar => bar.GetValue1()).Returns(1);
barMock.Setup(bar => bar.GetValue2Async()).ReturnsAsync(2);
```

Comment: I find `Mock.Of` better for methods as well. `var barMock = Mock.Of<Bar>(bar => bar.GetValue1() == 1)` . `var barMock = Mock.Of<Bar>(bar => bar.GetValue2Async() == Task.FromResult(1))`

Answer (score 6):

Both do the same but with `Mock.Of` it's more "natural" code.

Using `Mock<T>` looks more like this (or with Setup/Return like your code):

```cs
var mockService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
mockService.SetupProperty(s => s.IsActive);
mockService.Object.IsActive = true;
mockService.SetupProperty(s =>s.DelayTime);
mockService.Object.DelayTime = 5000;
```

Using `Mock.Of<T>` you get directly the instance and you can set the value you want.
And you can use `Mock.Get()` to configure any method:

```cs
var mockService = Mock.Of<ISomeService>();
mockService.IsActive = true;
mockService.DelayTime = 5000;
Mock.Get(mockService).Setup(s => s.ExecuteTask()).Returns(true);
```

They do the same, but for more complex services with a lot of properties and methods, I think `Mock.Of<T>` is more readable

Comment: Your example code for `Mock.Of<>()` only works if `ISomeService` has setters for `IsActive` and `DelayTime`. If it doesn't, declare like this: 
`var mockService = Mock.Of<ISomeService>(mockService => mockService.IsActive == true && mockService.DelayTime == 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

While the newer `Mock.Of` looks better and requires less coding, it does have limitations (as others have already pointed out).

However, it is indeed possible to do it via `Mock.Get()`.

For example, consider trying to get a mock with default values mocked, however there is no `DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock` on `Mock.Of()`, so in this case the following can be done:

```
var obj = Mock.Of<MyType>(t => SomeProp == Mock.Of<PropType>());

// We want SomeProp all sub properties to return mocks
Mock.Get(obj.SomeProp).DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock;

// Note that the following step wouldn't be required when using new Mock{DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock}
Mock.Get(obj.SomeProp).SetupAllProperties();
```

Answer (score 0):

The big difference I have noticed is that while `Mock.Of<T>(m => m.SomeMethod() == someResult)` is, IMHO, easier to use and much more readable, you can't set up methods to throw exceptions like you can using the old syntax - e.g. `new Mock<T>.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod()).Throws<Exception>();`

So you have to use the old way sometimes.

NOTE - If I am mistaken in this, please correct me, but I was not able to find anything on how to do this with the `Mock.Of<T>` syntax.  To be fair, I only searched for about 10m, but...yeah.

Comment: You can do:  `Mock.Get(Mock.Of<T>()).Setup(m => m.SomeMethod()).Throws()`, does that count? :)

Comment: I mean...I guess?  *insert Jeff Goldblum Jurassic Park meme here* 

Answer (score 0):

You can mock async methods like this using the Mock.Of syntax

```
var mockService = Mock.Of<ISomeService>(x => x.SomeMethodAsync() == Task.FromResult(myMockResults));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this post lacks a summary:

`Mock.Of<Object>()` returns the mocked instance of `Object` (the "mockee" if you want), while `new Mock<Object>()` returns the "mocker".

**1. Better readability of `Mock.Of<Object>()` esp. for mocking properties.**

**2. `Mock<Object>()` is a lot more flexible**. To access the full functionality, though, you need the mocker instead of the mocked instance. Among these features are:

- **Read-only properties**. I want to add: you can mock read-only properties with `new Mock<IReadOnlyObject>()`  but not with `Mock.Of<Object>()`.
- **Exceptions**. Methods throwing exceptions can be done with `new Mock<Object>.Setup(m => m.SomeMethod()).Throws<Exception>();`.
- **Sequences**. You can set up sequences of events.

```cs
   var mock = new Mock<IObject>();
   mock.SetupSequence(m => m.GetCount())
       .Returns(3)  // will be returned on 1st invocation
       .Returns(2); // will be returned on 2nd invocation
```

- **Callbacks**.

etc.

---

`Mock.Of<Object>()` can overcome these disadvantages using `Mock.Get(Mock.Of<Object>())`. Now you can use `Setup`, `SetupSequence`, etc. But it's a detour and we lose the advantage of readability.

The other way round, we can directly set properties of the mocked instance with `mock.Object` (see below). It will not work with [`MockBehavior.Strict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996327/moq-strict-vs-loose-usage), though, while setting the property using `Mock.Of<Object>()` will work also work for strict mocks.

```cs
   var mock = new Mock<IObject>();
   mock.Object.SomeProperty = 5;
```

*<sub>Feel free to add more insight to this summary</sub>*