# Error trying to create Mock.Of<ControllerContext>() for ASP.Net Core 3.1 Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

As per last section of the Moq Quickstart defined [here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), I am trying to configure the following Mock in order to pass Form values to the controller method under test:

```
var formCollection = new FormCollection(
                new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>()
            {
                    {"mAction", "someAction" },
                    {"mRefId", "0" }
            });

        var controllerContext = Mock.Of<ControllerContext>(ctx =>
            ctx.HttpContext.Request.Form == formCollection);
        
        controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;
```

However, when the run the test, it fails on the `Mock.Of<>` line with the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: mock => mock.HttpContext
>
> Non-overridable members (here: ActionContext.get_HttpContext) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

What am I missing?  Am I not doing it the same as per the example defined in the Quickstart document?

Comment: [`ControllerContext.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext) property is not *`virtual`*, so mock is unable to override it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because [`ControllerContext.HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext) property is not *`virtual`*, so Moq is unable to override it.

Consider using an actual [`ControllerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllercontext?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and mocking a `HttpContext` to assign to the property

```
var formCollection = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
    {
        {"mAction", "someAction" },
        {"mRefId", "0" }
    });

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
    HttpContext = Mock.Of<HttpContext>(ctx => ctx.Request.Form == formCollection)
};

controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

//...
```

Or even using `DefaultHttpContext` and assign the desired value(s)

```
var formCollection = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
    {
        {"mAction", "someAction" },
        {"mRefId", "0" }
    });

HttpContext httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
httpContext.Request.Form = formCollection;

var controllerContext = new ControllerContext() {
    HttpContext = httpContext
};

controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

//...
```

Comment: Thanks @Nkosi that worked!  I wonder if there is a bug in the Moq quickstart documentation then.  But thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually set all properties which are not marked `virtual` either by explicitly setting them in the lambda, or possibly setting them outside (there is no need to create a concrete object), this works by me at least in version 4.16.1.

Method 1 (when using `Mock.Of()`):

```
var mockCtx = Mock.Of<ControllerContext>(ctx =>
        ctx.HttpContext == Mock.Of<HttpContext>(hCtx => hCtx.Request.Form 
== formCollection))`
```

NOTE: In case you need to set all properties to be mocked, or do anything that needs `Mock.Get()` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72166303/640195) you need to do it directly on the `HttpContext` as in `Mock.Get(mockCtx.HttpContext )` and not on the `mockCtx`.

Method 2 (when using `new Mock<>()`):

```
var mockCtx = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
mockCtx.Object.HttpContext = Mock.Of<HttpContext>(hCtx => hCtx.Request.Form
                                                         == formCollection);
```

There is no need to create a concrete object, as method 2 is just doing the same but with a mock object.

Note: This will only work if the property is not readonly.